# Should I define template only attributes on my controller as well?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a simple toggle variable on the template of my directive

```
<div ng-mouseenter="$ctrl.myToggle = true" ng-mouseleave="$ctrl.myToggle = false">
...
</div>
<div ng-if="$ctrl.myToggle">
... toggled content
</div>
```

I am writing my controllers with typescript.

Should I define `myToggle` on my controller class, although it will never be used? (I do not need a toggle function since it's the only attributes that has to change)

```
export MyController {

  public myToggle:boolean = false;

  construtctor(){
    //...
  }

  //...
}
```

is it bad practice to have that kind of logic in my template only?

Comment: I guess 'attribute' should be replaced with 'property'. It makes the impression that the question is about DOM, while it concerns OOP.

Answer (score 0):

A controller and a template (view) are both parts of a single entity - a directive/component. This is the concept that was further developed in Angular 2, where controller classes are called directive/component classes.

Since it is supposed to be used by the component itself, it is correct to designate property visibility as `private`.

The lack of getter/setter `toggle()` method may be considered a bad practice in some cases because its presence benefits encapsulation and testability, but having `toggle` property instead is absolutely the same thing in current case.